# Forced material refreshing before render

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor, add-on

I am no familiar with scripting, but I can't see another way to solve my problem with material updating in *Animation*, so help me please.

Render engine is **Blender Render** and this button is a part of built-in **Node Wrangler** add-on.
Basic scenarion for the script is to select *Output* node in a list of materials (or at least one material) and click this *Reset* button on every frame change.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to automatically click that button, so tried to cut/create link between *Output* and previous node.

This code is kind of refreshes material named "Material" before rendering (at least my case).

```
import bpy
def remove_link(scene):
   mat = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree
   node1 = mat.nodes['Mix']
   node2 = mat.nodes['Output']
   links = mat.links
   link = node1.outputs[0].links[0]
   links.remove(link)
   link = links.new(node1.outputs[0], node2.inputs[0])

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(remove_link)
```